# Obtener fecha actual

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un SP que me  guarda datos en una tabla, Pero necesito que al ejecutarse guarde la hora actual en la que se hizo la insercion, el campo fecha iria despues de el `@valorcampo`

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[SP_1]
@valorcampo varchar(80)
as

insert into ValorCampoIndicador values ('D02','NEI',@valorcampo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mediante la funcion `GETDATE()` Puedes insertar la fecha actual en el campo, si dices que el campo va despues del parametro te quedaria algo como asi

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[SP_1]
@valorcampo varchar(80)
as

insert into ValorCampoIndicador values ('D02','NEI',@valorcampo,GETDATE())
```

prueba a ver que tal